# is there shorthand for nest foreach loops in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

More of a curiosity question.  If you have an array of arrays, is there any shorthand for iterating over the interior arrays?  You can obviously use the following to do it, but I wondered if there's a single line call that gets rid of the second foreach.

```
$arr = array(array(1,2,3), array(4,5,6), array(7,8,9));
foreach($arr as $interiorArr)
{
   foreach($interiorArr as $number)
   {
     echo $number;
   }
}
```

output would be "123456789"

Comment: I think it would be best to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320259/5884896

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: I just provided a very simple data example.  I was more looking for some syntax that might exist to structure the code more like "foreachMember($arr as $number){echo $number;}  Something to save those 3 lines of code and make it more readable.  Every nest can add confusion to someone not familiar with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're needing to do, you can recursively walk the array:

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v) { echo $v; });
```

For this simple example (`echo` and `print` aren't functions so can't be used as a callback):

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, 'printf');
```

Again, depending on what you're needing to do, and for this simple example, you can `foreach` and use a variety of functions that operates on arrays:

```
foreach($arr as $interiorArr)
{
     echo implode($interiorArr);
}
```

Comment: For this simple example yes I agree with your implode, but if the logic in the nested function is more complex not so much.  I suppose you could write another function for your logic and walk it recursively, but I don't see how that would simplify the code in any way.